# How does one authenticate a machine with active directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a project where I'm running a service that doesn't really care which user is signed in. But, I'd like to authenticate the machine, as in, make sure the machine is part of the domain. When I search for it (here and elsewhere) everything seems to come up related to authenticating users. I've seen in the AD console that you can see machines that are joined. How do I check that in C#? Or, is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? You just want to check that the machine is joined to any domain or are you wanting to do a task on the network and you want the machine's credentials to be the one authenticated (not hard to do, just want to make sure exactly what you are trying to do)?

Comment: I just want to check if the machine running my service is part of the domain.